# How can we access interceptor preHandle HanderMethod?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request, interceptor

I have written a interceptor to make some changes before service call in my spring boot rest service.

Added picture to show my code how I written preHandle method.

In the picture, I want to bring the "orginationTaskServerMockEnabled = true" value which is in
handler -> bean-> mHandler -> dashboardConfig-> originationTaskServerMockEnabled

I tried by it doesnt, is it possible to bring the values from HanlderMethod. If so please help me.

[image]

Comment: How did u try extract it from `dashboardConfig`?

Comment: Tried with HandlerMethod. But I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access the handler arguments in the interceptor's `preHandle`. It is called before the actual invocation of the handler method. The resolution of actual argument types is done during its invocation, so during the execution of `preHandle`, the argument's value are not resolved yet (but are described by `Object handler` argument). Only `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are known during the execution so, if the data is attached to the request, you can grab it from there.

Alternatively, you can use an aspect and wrap it around your controller method. From there, you can grab the method arguments then perform your preprocessing.

```
@Around("execution (* com.pck.controllers.*.*(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
public Object beforeHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint p){
    Object args[] = joinpoint.getArgs();
    return joinpoint.proceed();
}
```